# Where do you place an enum if you want your whole class to have access? (Objective - C)

Tags: objective-c

I want to create an enum that is global.  I've seen examples where they are declared within a method, but i want mine to be accessible by the whole class or even by the whole project (if possible)

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2):

Put it at the file level, inside a header.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the whole project to have access, put it in your class's `.h` file.  If you want access in your class, put it in your class's `.m` file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to define it for the entire project without importing a header everytime you could put it in the precompiled prefix header. That's the file that's named something like "???Prefix.pch".